# Simple code - Unresolved external symbol - c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
//class1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class class1
{
public:
    int var;
    class1(int i)
    {
        var = i;
    }
};

//class1.h:
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class class1
{
public:
    int var;
    class1(int i = 0);
};

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "class1.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class1 a(5);

    return 0;
}
```

error:
    1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall    class1::class1(int)" (??0class1@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in function _main

what the heck is going on? I swear I've made almost the exact same program before and It's worked.

Comment: So you're defining `class1` both in the header and in the cpp?

Comment: well, is there a makefile?
And as Andy said, it is not clever to define the same class twice. And furthermore: What do you mean with "almost the exact same..."?

Comment: As Andy mentioned, it looks like you have the same method declared in both your header and source file. Try putting class1::class1(int i) : var(i) {} in your source file.

Comment: thanks everyone for helping me out. you guys rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change class1.cpp to something like:

```
//class1.cpp
#include "class1.h"

class1::class1(int i) : var(i) {}
```

You don't want to define the class itself again -- just define the member functions in the implementation file.

Then you'll build it something like:

```
g++ main.cpp class1.cpp
```

[of course, substituting the correct compiler name for the compiler you're using]

Comment: If I do that then i will be including the file twice. right? once in the main file and once in class1.cpp?

Comment: @user2565979: Yes, that's correct. You want to include the header in both (instead of re-defining the class) to ensure they get matching definitions of the class.

Comment: Thank you very much! this was very helpful. I'm taking an online course and this explained it better than it did. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are not compiling both cpp files.  Check your build settings and make sure that both `main.cpp` and `class1.cpp` are being compiled.

However you also have a serious problem.  You are declaring `class1` *twice*. Once in the header:

```
class class1
{
public:
    int var;
    class1(int i = 0);
};
```

... and again in the cpp:

```
class class1
{
public:
    int var;
    class1(int i)
    {
        var = i;
    }
};
```

In C++ there should be exactly one declaration for a class (and exactly one definition).

The way it works is you declare the class in your header, as you have already done, and then you *define* the members in the cpp, like this:

### class1.cpp

```
#include "class1.h"

class1::class1(int i)
{
    var = i;
}
```